# Why name based virtualhost applies to ip requests?

Tags: apache, configuration-files, web-hosting

I use apache2, ubuntu server 8.

I created a name based virtualhost.
I created the file mydomain.com and this is its content:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
   ServerName www.mydomain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/htdocs/
   ServerAlias mydomain.com
   ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I placed it in:
/etc/apache2/sites-available
and then activated it through
    a2ensite mydomain.com
and reloaded apache conf files.

The problem is that now both if I type in the browser mydomain.com OR xx.xx.xx.xx (the ip address) this VirtualHost is loaded in both the cases!
I know that for a fact because the content is served by /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/htdocs/ in both the kinds of request.
I expect this not to happen when the IP is typed.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you add a hard-coded IP-based host configuration? If not, Apache will use the first vhost that uses the IP in question.

Comment: I did not because there was a default configuration:
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ....
    </VirtualHost>
before I added mine. Do you think I should?

Comment: Apache's somewhat touchy about the order you specify vhosts, especially when mixing IP and name-based hosts. Try reversing the order they're listed in and see if that helps.

Comment: You are right. That needs to be a hard-coded IP-based host configuration instead of *:80.
This solved the problem.
Thanks

Comment: @Matteo Please mention that in an answer to your question, then.